# How to fix my oracle LCConnection charset override warning message

Tags: oracle, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

When creating an Oracle LCConnection in LotusScript for my IBM Notes application to access my Oracle Inventory server data, I get a weird warning message.

The warning message is the following:

> Connector message: Character set overriding 'Overriding Oracle
>   codepage to AL32UTF8 (LCSTREAMFMT 171) from source Oracle Server', 
>   Connector 'oracle',  Method

To get this warning message, I used the following diagnostic code in my IBM Notes application:

```
If (gLCSession.status = LCSUCCESS) Then
    connect = True
    gIsConnected = True
    Print "Connexion établie"
Else
    Dim statusTxt As String
    Dim extcode As Long
    Dim exttext As String
    Call gLCSession.GetStatus (statusTxt,  extcode, exttext)
    If (gLCSession.Status = LCFAIL_EXTERNAL) Then
        Print "External fail message: " & exttext & "  code #" & CStr(extcode)
    Else
        Print "Connector message: " & statusTxt
    End If
End If
```

My applications are running on an IBM Domino server 9.0.1 FP10 x64 on a Windows Server 2012 x64. An Oracle client 12.1.0.2 x64 is also installed on this server to communicate with the Oracle Inventory EBS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I realised my Oracle Inventory server is set to receive AL32UTF8 character set messages.

In order to quiet this client oracle connector message, I modified my Notes.ini file in my Domino server with the following value:

> EIOracle8NativeText=AL32UTF8

This is ok with me because it doesn't impact negatively the other apps on my Domino server.

Alternatively, I have read [here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/using-the-auto-codepage-feature-of-ibm-lotus-connector-for-oracle-8.x) that this can be configured at the Oracle client level by assigning AL32UTF8 to the NLS_LANG registry key. An other option is to inject the charset as a parameter when calling the LCConnection streaming function.